# System of Fourier coefficient ODEs finding constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, systems-of-equations, fourier-series

Let $$u(t,x) = \sum_{n=1}^3 a_n(t) \phi_n\left(\frac{x}{L}\right), \quad \text{with} \quad \phi_n\left(\frac{x}{L}\right) = \sqrt{2}\cos\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2L}x \right) \tag 1$$

which is the Galerkin approximation of the solution $u(t,x)$ of the PDE:

$$
u_{tt}(t,x) = u_{xx}(t,x)+u_{txx}(t,x) - u_t(t,x)
$$

with boundary conditions $u_x(t,0) = u(t,L) = 0$.

and

$$
\ddot{a}_n(t) = -\frac{(2n-1)\pi^2}{4L^2}a_n(t) - \left( 1 + \frac{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}{4L^2}\right)\dot{a}_n(t), \quad n = 1,2,3 \tag 2
$$
with initial conditions:

$$
u(0,x) = C(x^2-x^3), \quad u_t(0,x) \equiv 0 \tag 3
$$

The objective is to determine the functions $a_n(t), \, n=1,2,3$ from the ode system and the initial conditions for $L=1$.

### Attempt:

Solving each of the $3$ equations we obtain the general solutions:
$$
\begin{align}
a_1(t) & = c_1e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{4}t} + c_2e^{-t} \\
a_2(t) & = c_3e^{-\frac{9\pi^2}{4}t} + c_4e^{-t} \\
a_3(t) & = c_5e^{-\frac{25\pi^2}{4}t} + c_6e^{-t}
\end{align} \tag 4
$$
and through the initial conditions:
$$
\begin{align}
a_1(0) + a_2(0) + a_3(0) & = 0 \\
\dot{a}_1(0) + \dot{a}_2(0) + \dot{a}_3(0) & = 0
\end{align} \tag 5
$$
but the above equations alone don't determine $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5,c_6)$ uniquely.

What other equations can be used to find these constants?

Comment: Where is $x$ gone in your initial conditions? Is there an underlying PDE governing $u(t,x)$? Commonly, you have to project the initial condition on the family $\phi_i$, which seems to be missing here...

Comment: @pluton done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal system of ODE (2) was probably obtained as follows (I haven't checked but the $\phi_i$ seem to be orthogonal to each other with the scalar product $\int_0^L \phi_i\phi_k\mathrm{d}x$):
$$\forall i=1,2,3,\quad\int_0^L\phi_i(x)\Bigl(\sum_{k=1}^{3}\ddot{a}_k(t)\phi_k(x)+\dot{a}_k(t)\phi_k(x)-a_k(t)\phi_{k,xx}(x)-\dot{a}_k(t)\phi_{k,xx}(x)\Bigr)\mathrm{d}x=0$$
The same applies to initial conditions, that is (to be computed; there might be a missing scaling factor):
$$\forall i=1,2,3,\quad a_i(0)=\int_0^L\phi_i(x) C(x^2-x^3)\mathrm{d}x$$
(stemming from $\sum_{k=1}^3a_k(0)\phi_k(x)=C(x^2-x^3)$ and projection on the $\phi_i$)
and
$$\forall i=1,2,3,\quad \dot{a}_i(0)=\int_0^L\phi_i(x) \times0\,\mathrm{d}x=0$$
so that you can solve uniquely for your six unknown coefficients $c_i$, $i=1,\ldots,6$ as soon as $C$ is given.

Comment: Very clear and thorough elaboration. Thank you!